# type error from bytes32 to uint256 but I properly declared it. In solidity

Tags: solidity

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:GPX-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract sol {
    struct student {
        string name;
        uint256 ID;
        string grade;
    }
    bytes32[] private student_Address;
    mapping(bytes32=>student) private studentMap;

    uint256 private index = 0;
    function createNewStudent(string memory _name, uint256 _id, string memory _grade) public {
        student_Address.push(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(index)));
        studentMap[student_Address[index]] = student(_name, _id, _grade);
        index++;
    }

    function getStudentInfo(uint256 num) public view returns (bytes32, student memory) {
        return (student_Address[num], studentMap[num]); // line 21
    }
}
```

where I have a problem is line 21 :return (student_Address[num], studentMap[num]);

The error message is:
TypeError: Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes32

but I don't understand why there's type error.

Because return type of student_Address[num] is bytes32, and I properly declared it.
And uint256 num is just a index.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert num type from uint256 to bytes32

```
return (student_Address[bytes32(num)], studentMap[bytes32(num)]);
```

hope it work for you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with `student_Address[num]`, but with `studentMap[num]`.

`studentMap` is a mapping where the key of type `bytes32`. However `num` is of type `uint256`, so you're trying to access the mapping value with an incorrect key type.

Based on how you store the data in `createNewStudent()`, you need to retrieve it using `student_Address[num]` as the key of the `studentMap` mapping.

```
function getStudentInfo(uint256 num) public view returns (bytes32, student memory) {
    bytes32 key = student_Address[num];
    return (
        key,
        studentMap[key]
    );
}
```